# LEFT OUTER JOIN with INNER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of students.
and a table of teachers.

SOME of the students (not all) will have a teacher assigned to them.
this is controlled in a 3rd table, matching those students with their teachers, via the studentID and teacherID

what i need the SQL to do, is to `LEFT OUTER JOIN` onto the 3rd table, which is then `INNER JOINED` onto the teacher's table  (because not all students will appear in the 3rd table, but any teacher that appears in the 3rd table WILL appear in the teachers table).

i am looking to get a result of all student names, and teacher's name, where they are assigned (and null if not).

what i have so far looks like this, and it basically operates as a full INNER JOIN, and does not give me students who do not have teachers assigned:

```
SELECT firstname, teacherlastName
FROM tblstudents 

left outer join [tblStudentRakazot] 
ON tblstudents.studentid = [tblStudentRakazot].studentID 

INNER JOIN tblteachers 
ON [tblStudentRakazot].teacherid = tblteachers.teacherID
```

can someone pls give me a pointer here? i tried with placing brackets, but that didn't see, to help.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use an `INNER JOIN` but only another `LEFT JOIN`.

Think of tblStudents as your base. You want to get all of them, not filter anything out, and only attach optional info.
With the first left join, you attach a first info
Student -> TeacherAssignment
The TeacherAssignment can be null or not null.
Now you only attach another info - the teacher's full name pulled from `tblTeachers`.
Student -> TeacherAssignnent -> TeacherName
Do this with another `LEFT JOIN`. That attaches the info, where possible, i.e. where TeacherAssignment is not null.
This ignores rows where TeacherAssignment is null anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You could move your `INNER JOIN` to a subquery

```
SELECT  firstname, teacherlastName
FROM    tblstudents 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (   SELECT  [tblStudentRakazot].studentID, tblTeachers.teacherlastName
            FROM    [tblStudentRakazot]
                    INNER JOIN tblteachers 
                        ON [tblStudentRakazot].teacherid = tblteachers.teacherID
        ) teachers
            ON tblstudents.studentid = teachers.studentID
```

Another option is to use a more complicated where clause.

```
SELECT  firstname, teacherlastName
FROM    tblstudents 
        LEFT JOIN [tblStudentRakazot] 
            ON tblstudents.studentid = [tblStudentRakazot].studentID 
        LEFT JOIN tblteachers 
            ON [tblStudentRakazot].teacherid = tblteachers.teacherID
WHERE   [tblStudentRakazot] IS NULL
OR      tblteachers.teacherID IS NOT NULL
```

However, SQL Server is pretty good at propogating predicates out of subqueries where it needs to, so I would favour the first approach for both readabilty and efficiency.

**EDIT**

I did not read the question properly, I thought you did not want records where the teacherID in `tblStudentRakazot` was NULL. If this is not an issue then you can simply use two LEFT JOINS, without the where clause as above:

```
SELECT  firstname, teacherlastName
FROM    tblstudents 
        LEFT JOIN [tblStudentRakazot] 
            ON tblstudents.studentid = [tblStudentRakazot].studentID 
        LEFT JOIN tblteachers 
            ON [tblStudentRakazot].teacherid = tblteachers.teacherID
```

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if I've misunderstood something: He just wants the Students and the assigned teachers or null for the teacher. There should be no need for any WHERE part at all in your second query...

Comment: @KekuSemau I did not read the question properly, I thought the OP did not want records where the teacherID in tblStudentRakazot was NULL, which is why I thought the where clause was required, you are right, it isn't required.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT firstname, teacherlastName
FROM tblstudents 
left outer join
( select * from
 [tblStudentRakazot] A INNER JOIN tblteachers B 
ON A.teacherid = B.teacherID)AS C
ON tblstudents.studentid = C.studentID
```

Comment: thanks for this, you answer was very helpful, because it enabled me to use a `WHERE` clause on the inner `SELECT`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.student_firstname, teacherlastName
FROM thirdtable a 
left join studenttbl b on a.studentid = b.studentid
left join teachertbl b on a.teacherid = b.teacherid
```

You can always use outer join if you are certain data in teacher table is unique. it will give same result as inner join.

Answer (score 0):

You may not use a subquery as in @GarethD sample.

```
SELECT firstname, teacherlastName
FROM tblstudents
LEFT OUTER JOIN [tblStudentRakazot]
    INNER JOIN tblteachers
        ON [tblStudentRakazot].teacherid = tblteachers.teacherID
    ON tblstudents.studentid = [tblStudentRakazot].studentID
```

But when looking more deeply execution plans of this query and query with subquery will likely be equivalent.